# How to extract from a file text between tokens using bash scripts

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I was reading this question: [Extract lines between 2 tokens in a text file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-text-from-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash)
because I have a very similar problem...
I have to extract (and save it to $variable before printing) text in this xml file:

```
<--more labels up this line>
<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastVMSelected" value="14cd3204-4774-46b8-be89-cc834efcba89"/>
<--more labels and text down this line-->
```

I only need to get the value= (obviously without brackets and no 'value='), but first, I think it have to search "GUI/LastVMSelected" to get to this line, because there could be a similar value field in other lines,and the value of that label is that i want.

Comment: If this is a xml/html, you should consider to use a proper xml parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are on the same line (as they seem to be from your example), it's even easier. Just:

```
sed -ne '/name="GUI\/LastVMSelected"/s/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

Explanation:

- -n: Suppress default print
- /name="GUI\/LastVMSelected"/: only lines matching this pattern
- s/.*value="([^"])".*/\1/p

  - substitute everything, capturing the parenthesized part (the value of value)
  - and print the result

Comment: Thanks, it works! but I need to catch it in a $variable because I need it in a script.

Comment: So why not just use `varname=`sed whatever`` (note the backticks)?

Comment: I found a way:VAR=$(sed -ne '/name="GUI\/LastVMSelected"/s/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' /some/place.xml)
echo $VAR

That's the way that I want. Now I can use variable $VAR in some part of the script

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're extracting from an XML document. If that is the case, have a look at the [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command-line tools for processing XML. There's some documentation for querying XML docs [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for f in `grep "GUI/LastVMSelected" filename.txt | cut -d " " -f3`; do echo ${f:7:36}; done
```

- `grep` gets you only the lines you need
- `cut` splits the lines using some separator, and returns the Nth result of the split
- `-d " "` sets the separator to space
- `-f3` returns the third result (1-based indexing)
- `${f:7:36}` extracts the substring starting at index 7 that is 36 characters long.  This gets rid of the leading `value="` and trailing slash, etc.

Obviously if the order of the fields changes, this will break, but if you're just after something quick and dirty that works, this should be it.

Comment: That does not strip the value= and quotes.

Comment: That depends on the string being at a particular position in the line and is not at all reliable. It also breaks the line up on white space so it wouldn't even work if it were.

Comment: I've specifically said that **"if the order of the fields changes, this will break"**.  Nobody sane would expect that to be reliable after reading that disclaimer.

Comment: It seems that using sed get a most clean output, but I still need to catch the value in a variable, because I need it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Using my answer from the question you linked:

```
sed -n '/<!--more labels up this line-->/{:a;n;/<!--more labels and text down this line-->/b;\|GUI/LastVMSelected|s/value="\([^=]*\)"/\1/p;ba}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `-n` - don't do an implicit print
- `/<!-- this is token 1 -->/{` - if the starting marker is found, then

  - `:a` - label "a"

    - `n` - read the next line
    - `/<!-- this is token 2 -->/q` - if it's the ending marker, quit
    - `\|GUI/LastVMSelected|` - if the line matches the string

      - `s/value="\([^"]*\)"/\1/p` - print the string after 'value=' and before the next quote
  - `ba` - branch to label "a"
- `}` end if