# Get random text block from file using bash

Tags: bash, random, token

what is the simplest way of reading a random block of characters from a text file using bash?

A block is a set of characters which begin with `X` and end with `X`, where `X` is a character sequence, usually it will be `"\n\n"`

We can assume that file has short lines, less than 200 characters each.
Blocks don't have more than 20 lines.

I have seen threads like [get random line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line), [get text from between two tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-text-from-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash), but it's not exacly what I need.

I can write a simple program in C that will read how many blocks are in file, get a random number from a given range and then search for a block with this ID, but there must be an easier way.

Example:
`X = "\n\n"`

File: (the `.`'s are not in the file, I used them to make "empty" line at the begginning and end of code)

```
.
first line
second line and some other text

fourth line

sixth line
seventh line, more textęęę
.
```

Running the script for first time, output:

```
fourth line
```

Running the script for the second time, output:

```
first line
second line and some other text
```

Yours faithfully,
user2420535

Comment: Can you show a sample of input file and your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a uniformly random block from a file of blank-line-separated blocks in one pass,

```
awk -v RS='\n\n'  '
  BEGIN { srand(); } 
  rand() < 1.0/NR { s=$0; }  
  END { print s; }
  '   file
```

This is a simple case of [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: Nicely done; so others aren't tempted to incorrectly optimize either: the algorithm _must_  loop over _all_ input records. BSD `awk` (and the POSIX spec.), sadly, doesn't support multi-char. `RS` values; the closest approximation is to use `-v RS=` for paragraph mode, which, however, allows _any_ number of empty lines to separate the blocks.