# How to extract between to tokens in text file using bash and manipulate output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have a large text file with blocks of text between two tokens I want to extract and put into a new file. I want each block extracted to go on single line (each block has its own line).

I used this solution: [Extract lines between 2 tokens in a text file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-lines-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash)

```
sed -n '/<!-- this is token 1 -->/{:a;n;/<!-- this is token 2 -->/b;p;ba}' inputfile
```

and it worked almost perfectly. the problem I have is that the block extracted is two lines and I want to condense it to one line. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
<token1>
text to
extract
<token2>
<token1>
text to
extract
<token2>
```

output should look like:

```
text to extract
text to extract
```

Comment: you can use `awk -v RS="<token[[:digit:]]>" '{$1=$1} /./{print $0}'  inputfile` if your tokens are really like as you mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by separately running:

```
sed -e '/pattern/N;y/\n/\t/'
```

on my file after the first solution

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is more suited for this sort of text processing than `sed`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
<token1>
text to
foo
extract
<token2>
<token1>
text to
extract
123
bar foo
baz
<token2>

$ awk '/<token1>/{f=1; next} /<token2>/{print a; a=""; f=0} f{a = a ? a" "$0 : $0}' ip.txt 
text to foo extract
text to extract 123 bar foo baz
```

Similar solution with `perl`

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/<token1>/){$f=1; next} if(/<token2>/){print "@a"; undef @a; $f=0}; push(@a,$_) if $f' ip.txt 
text to foo extract
text to extract 123 bar foo baz
```

or

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/<token1>/){$f=1; next} if(/<token2>/){print $a; $a=""; $f=0}; $a .= $a?" $_":$_ if $f' ip.txt 
text to foo extract
text to extract 123 bar foo baz
```