# How to extract multiple patterns between tokens at once with sed?

Tags: xml, bash, sed, xmlstarlet

Let's assume that i have file named inputFile which looks like that:

```
blahblah token substring token something else token substring2 token
```

Whole file contain only 1 long line.

I want to extract substrings between tokens with sed (substring,substring2).

At this moment I have:

```
[sed "s/^.* \?token\(.* \)token.* \?/\1/"][1] inputFile > outputFile
```

I try to do this based on these questions, but unfortunately it returns only last substring

[Extract lines between 2 tokens in a text file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-lines-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash/4857466#4857466)

[How to replace multiple patterns at once with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568952/how-to-replace-multiple-patterns-at-once-with-sed/26568996#26568996)

[How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/38972737#38972737)

Answers with explanation will be great.

***UPDATE***
real input code:

```
<archive><message id="0"><receiver>apr</receiver><sender>gtr</sender><text>52333</text><sendTime>554</sendTime><deliveryTime>765</deliveryTime></message><message id="0"><receiver>apr</receiver><sender>gtr</sender><text>4332</text><sendTime>764</sendTime><deliveryTime>922</deliveryTime></message></archive>
```

Expected output:

```
apr gtr 52333
apr gtr 4332
```

Comment: Is there not a missing `<archive>` in the beginning?

Comment: you'll have to add on what basis output is arrived at.. also, if it is valid xml, use an xml parser like xmlstarlet or a programming language with xml module..

Comment: @kvantour Yes, indeed

Comment: @MariuszBakun I have updated my answer with an `xmlstarlet` cmd that provides the requested output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `sed` is greedy so the above command will only return `substring2` if you add the global flag (`g`) :

You could use `awk` for this where you redefine the fieldseparator `FS` to be the string `token`. This way your strings are on the even field positions :

```
$ echo "blahblah token substring token something else token substring2 token"  | \
  awk -F 'token' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {print $i}}'
 substring 
 substring2
```

**update:**

If your input is an xml-file you might want to do :

```
<archive>
   <message id="0">
       <receiver>apr</receiver>
       <sender>gtr</sender>
       <text>52333</text>
       <sendTime>554</sendTime>
       <deliveryTime>765</deliveryTime>
   </message>
   <message id="0">
       <receiver>apr</receiver>
       <sender>gtr</sender>
       <text>4332</text>
       <sendTime>764</sendTime>
       <deliveryTime>922</deliveryTime>
   </message>
 </archive>"
```

leading to the cmd :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//message' -v receiver -o " " -v sender -o " " -v text -n <file>
```

which outputs

```
apr gtr 52333
apr gtr 4332
```