# XML print each line in Bash

Tags: xml, bash, xml-parsing

I have an API that works fine. I pull XML data that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <buildings>
    <size>
      7
    </size>
      <building>
        <id>
          1
        </id>
          <name>
             First Building
          </name>
      </building>
      <building>
         <id>
           2
         </id>
           <name>
             Second Building
           </name>
      </building>
   </buildings>
```

Trying to print each building name as

```
First Building
Second Building
```

I've tried:

```
IDS=$(*fullcommand* | awk -F'>|<' '/<name>/ {print $3}')
printf '%s\n' $IDS
```

But this prints:

```
First
Building
Second
Building
```

Any help would be awesome.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use awk to parse some XML but have a look at any XML parser such as xmlint or xmlstarlet. They make use of very powerful regex-like expressions which are called XPath. With that, you will be 100% robust.

Comment: Put `$IDS` in quotes. In general, you should always quote variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: That simple. Im a noob.

Comment: Try this robust way: `$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Building" -v name -n file.xml` Equivlanent: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484506/). The reason to use an xmlparser is because an update to `fullcommand` might create a differently formatted XML output where the command might fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract multiple patterns between tokens at once with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484506/how-to-extract-multiple-patterns-between-tokens-at-once-with-sed)

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlstarlet select --template --match '//name' --value-of 'normalize-space()' -n file
```

Output:

```
First Building
Second Building
```

[The `normalize-space` function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut out between "name" and "/name"

```
sed -n '/<name>/,/<\/name>/p' | grep -v '^ *<' | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: It is better, but it depends on what user2720970 wants.